# Supervised learning algorithms for classification, that we should read first

Tags: machine-learning, classification

What are the main supervised learning algorithms for classification (more than 2 classes), that we should learn first when we are beginners in that domain ?
It is good if you can also give easy-to-understand tutorials for the algorithms that you propose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with:

- Naive Bayesian Classifiers
- Support Vector Machines, and
- Decision Trees

since they cover a) the probabilistic description of this type of problem, b) the geometrical/linear-algebra description of this type of problem, and c) the divide and conquer description of this type of problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have 3 requests: (1) Do you have some reading suggestions that are easy-to-understand for this three propositions ? (2) Is any one of this three classifiers better than the two others in some situations ? i.e. Is there known situations where one of these is better than the others. (3) Is Support Vector Machines only for for classification problems with only two classes ?

Comment: It doesn't cover Bayesian classifier, but a starting reference that I always use is _The Elements of Statistical Learning_ by T. Hastie et al.

Answer (score 2):

Good points made by Dave. I would also add kNN as an example of non-parametric method. Besides is widely used in practice and every practitioner should now about it. With non-parametric I mean that the method is based on data only, and it makes no assumption of the particular form of the actual probability distribution of the input data.

Comment: Well ok, KNN is the first classification algorithm that I used. It is very simple, there no really a learning phase, the model is just a copy of the dataset.